# sap.ui.table.Table - Select Row Programmatically by Content

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.ui.table.Table whose `selectionMode` is `Single` and `selectionBehavior` is `RowOnly`.

I want to select a row programmatically based on content;

There is code to select by index like

1. table.setSelectedIndex()
2. table.setSelectionInterval()

but I am not able to get the index of the content, whose row is to be selected.

Is there any other way?

Comment: May I ask what you'd like to do with the selection? What's the use case? The `sap.ui.table.Table` has an architecture that supports handling huge amount of data by loading only parts of them. Therefore I'm afraid it's currently not possible to select a certain row by content without having the content loaded in the first place.

Comment: ok. There are 2 tables whose single select modes (row) are turned on. Each row of a table can be mapped to a particular row of the other table (There is a map button for this). This mapping info is saved in DB. After mapping all rows, if i select one row of one table, the mapped row of the other should be automatically selected, for the user to know.

Comment: Can't you filter the other table and select the row remaining?

Comment: @MatthijsMennens nope, cause if i filter i won't be able to select the other rows of the filtered table.

Comment: How are the tables mapped in your database? Is there some sort of unique identifier?

Comment: @EnuM of course there is an id for each table. There are 3 db tables including one to store the mapping info.

Answer (score 3):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325596/sap-ui-table-select-row-programmatically-by-content#comment91689140_52325596) in the question, there is currently no straightforward solution to select row(s) programmatically by content. But I read:

> I want an answer that works. Best practices/ suggestions are not accepted.

If that's still the case, I assume you're ok with accessing internal properties. The only internal property I'm using is the `aKeys` from the *ODataListBinding* instance. The following snippets are from this example: [https://embed.plnkr.co/7lcVJOaYsnIMJO1w](https://embed.plnkr.co/7lcVJOaYsnIMJO1w?show=controller/Table.controller.js,preview) <sup>[1]</sup>

### Single Select

```xml
<Table xmlns="sap.ui.table"
  id="myGridTable"
  selectionMode="Single"
  selectionBehavior="RowOnly"
  rows="{
    path: '/Customers',
    events: {
      change: '.onRowsDataChange'
    }
  }"
>
  <!-- columns -->
</Table>
```

```js
Controller.extend("demo.controller.TableSingleSelect", {
  onRowsDataChange: function(event) {
    this.selectCustomer(/*your key part(s) e.g.:*/ "ANTON"/*, ...*/);
  },

  selectCustomer: function(customerId/*, ...*/) {
    const rowsBinding = this.byId("myGridTable").getBinding("rows");
    this.selectIndexByKey(rowsBinding.getModel().createKey("Customers", {
      CustomerID: customerId,
      //...
    }), rowsBinding.aKeys);
  },

  selectIndexByKey: function(targetKey, keys) {
    const table = this.byId("myGridTable");
    const index = +Object.keys(keys).find(key => targetKey === keys[key]);
    const shouldSelect = index > -1 && !table.isIndexSelected(index);
    return shouldSelect ? table.setSelectedIndex(index) : table;
  },

});
```

[image: OpenUI5 sap.ui.table.Table Single Select]

### Multi Select

```xml
<Table xmlns="sap.ui.table"
  id="myGridTable"
  selectionMode="MultiToggle"
  rows="{
    path: '/Orders',
    events: {
      change: '.onRowsDataChange'
    }
  }"
>
  <!-- columns -->
</Table>
```

```js
Controller.extend("demo.controller.TableMultiSelect", {
  onRowsDataChange: function(event) {
    const value1 = new Date("1996"); // 1996-01-01
    const value2 = new Date("1997"); // 1997-01-01
    this.selectOrdersBy("OrderDate", "BT", value1, value2);
  },

  selectOrdersBy: function(propertyName, filterOperator, value1, value2) {
    const table = this.byId("myGridTable").clearSelection();
    const keys = table.getBinding("rows").aKeys;
    const loadedContexts = this.getLoadedContexts(keys, table, "rows");
    const filteredContexts = FilterProcessor.apply(loadedContexts, [
      new Filter(propertyName, filterOperator, value1, value2),
    ], (context, path) => context && context.getProperty(path));
    this.selectIndices(keys, filteredContexts, table);
  },

  getLoadedContexts: function(keys, control, aggregationName) {
    const model = control.getBinding(aggregationName).getModel();
    const parameters = control.getBindingInfo(aggregationName).parameters;
    return keys.map(key => model.createBindingContext(`/${key}`, parameters));
  },

  selectIndices: (keys, contexts, table) => Object.keys(keys).map(index => +index)
    .filter(i => contexts.find(context => `/${keys[i]}` == context.getPath()))
    .map(i => table.isIndexSelected(i) || table.addSelectionInterval(i, i)),

});
```

<sup>* [FilterProcessor](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/FilterProcessor.js) is a private module.</sup>

[image: OpenUI5 sap.ui.table.Table MultiToggle Orders sorted]

The internal property `aKeys` consists of keys, from loaded contexts, with indices reflecting the table row indices. E.g.: If the table has 3 rows loaded and I call `table.getContextByIndex(90)`, the `aKeys` will be:

```
0: "Customers('ALFKI')"
1: "Customers('ANATR')"
2: "Customers('ANTON')"
90: "Customers('WOLZA')"
```

The [change](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Binding/events/change) handler `onRowsDataChange` is fired on any [ChangeReason](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.ChangeReason). This keeps the selection from being removed whatever happens to the table rows, be it sorting, filtering, refreshing, etc..

---

[1]: The samples in this answer work with an **ODataModel**. In case of a client-side **JSONModel**, take a look at this answer: [stackoverflow.com/a/52664812](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52664812/5846045).

Comment: Can you help me with this line of code .  const index = +Object.keys(keys).find(key => targetKey === keys[key]);    what is +object here?

Comment: @anil_pulikoden The [JS API `find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns a single array item that fulfills the condition `targetKey == keys[key]`. In our case, it's the _index_. But since the `Object.keys(keys)` is an array of indices **of type string**, I'm parsing the found _index_ to number via `+` operator. Setting a `+` before a string value is equivalent to `parseInt("42", 10)`

Comment: @anil_pulikoden I just added another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52664812/5846045, this time with a JSONModel.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your design you can for instance use a button receive the selected index:

```
oEvent.getSource().getParent().getIndex()
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/tyel123/k74tcwh9/)

Comment: this is in the click event, I presume. But I want to get the index or select  a  row with a particular value. For ex. if there is a table with ID and Name, I want to select row with value "steve jons"

Answer (score 1):

## JSONModel

There was another request to do it with a JSONModel. So here it is.

The following snippets are from [https://embed.plnkr.co/xuSU3uH1rkXmEAV7](https://embed.plnkr.co/xuSU3uH1rkXmEAV7?show=controller%2FTableSingleSelect.controller.js,preview):

```xml
<Table xmlns="sap.ui.table"
  id="myGridTable"
  selectionMode="Single"
  selectionBehavior="RowOnly"
  rows="{
    path: '/Customers',
    events: {
      change: '.onRowsDataChange'
    }
  }"
>
  <!-- columns -->
</Table>
```

```js
Controller.extend("demo.controller.TableSingleSelect", {
  onRowsDataChange: function(event) {
    this.selectWhere(context => context.getProperty("CustomerID") == "ANTON" /*&& ...*/);
  },

  selectWhere: function(keysAreMatching) {
    const table = this.byId("myGridTable");
    const contexts = table.getBinding("rows").getContexts();
    const index = this.getRowIndexWhere(keysAreMatching, contexts);
    return this.selectRowByIndex(index, table);
  },

  getRowIndexWhere: function(keysAreMatching, contexts) {
    let index = -1;
    contexts.find((context, i) => keysAreMatching(context) && (index = i));
    return index;
  },

  selectRowByIndex: function(i, table) {
    const shouldSelect = i > -1 && !table.isIndexSelected(i);
    return shouldSelect ? setTimeout(() => table.setSelectedIndex(i)) : table;
  },

});
```

With a client-side model like JSONModel, it is a bit easier to find certain row(s) than with server-side models since all necessary data are locally available via `rowsBinding.getContexts()`. The returned contexts are assigned to the indices corresponding to table's row indices.

Comment: About the `setTimeout(() => table.setSelectedIndex(i))`: This had to be done due to a bug in the framework. In the current nightly version (1.59.x), the bug is fixed so that the timeout is not needed anymore. Just do `table.setSelectedIndex(i)`.

Comment: do you think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52660400/3929188) also does the same thing?

Comment: @anil_pulikoden **Yes:** both solutions assume that the indices found in the binding relate directly to the row indices just like the [case w/ `aKeys`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52416004). **No:** The above solution leverages public APIs instead of internal properties. The `find` method offers the exact associated index which is important if the array has an incomplete series of indices: Given `[0, 1, 2, 3, 15, 16]`, you'd select a wrong row if you just increment the index to select by one. And finally, you have to keep in mind that the selection gets removed every time the rows change.

Answer (score 0):

This small piece of code did the work for me. Table is bound to JSONModel.

```
const rowsBinding = oTable.getBinding("rows");
var index1 = -1;
rowsBinding.oList.find(function(element){
    index1++;
    if(element.yourField== "your Content")
    {
     oTable.setSelectedIndex(index1);  
    }
});
```

Now i am able select my row on the basis of content.